Mixed-effects logistic model generating lower predicted values than observed in R
I have a dataframe of patients, with an outcome of cancer flagged, and other variables to be used as covariates (around 20 of these). The dataframe is made up of multiple cohorts which are flagged in a single column with a number to indicate cohort membership.



patid
cancer
age
sex
smoking_status
bmi_cat
cohort




00001
0
56
1
2
1
1


00002
0
54
1
1
2
1


00003
0
70
2
1
2
2



etc.
To allow varying interaction with age, I have one hot-encoded the cohort variable as in single-cohort models, some were found to have interaction with age.
My model form is something like:
glmer(cancer ~ ns(age_idate, df=3) + 
    ns(age_idate, df=3):(cohort_6,cohort_4,cohort_9) + cohort_6 + 
    cohort_4 + cohort_1 + cohort_2 + sex + bmi_cat + smoking_status + 
    fatigue...etc.  + (1|patid), family=binomial, data=model_data, 
    nAGQ=0, control=glmerControl(calc.derivs=FALSE)

When I use predict() to get predicted risk of cancer in the original model_data, I achieve reasonable predictions based on the results of my individual models and clinical knowledge.
However, I need to get predicted risk simply at each age (30-100) and sex (male,female) combination, rather than on an individual patient level, for each of the cohorts.
I create a dataframe of all age and sex combinations, and then append all other variables set to their base value (i.e. 0 in a 2 level factor), except from the cohort I am interested in, which I set to 1.



age
sex
smoking_status
bmi_cat
cohort_1
cohort_2




30
1
0
0
1
0


31
1
0
0
1
0


32
1
0
0
1
0



etc.
The code I use to predict is:
model_pred_cohort_1 <- marginaleffects::predictions(
                        model=mixed_effects_mod, newdata=grouped_data,
                        re.form=NA, type='response'
)

When I make predictions on this dataframe, the predicted risk for each age is much lower than expected. I've also tried adding in the patid variable with different random values, as I am not sure if this is needed, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.
My question is: is this the correct use of this model type, and is there a reason my model is outputting much lower risks than observed?
If I simply look in my model_data, filter by a specific cohort, and look at the proportion of patients with cancer vs not, it gives a higher value then the same combination of predicted values, but only when predicting onto each specific age and sex combination, not if I am just getting predicted risk for each patient in the population.
Sorry if the question is not clear or more information is required.
